# why remove element of deque Fail?

Tags: python, deque

I run code as follow:

```
q = deque([4,5,6,7,8])
for e in q:
    print("remove the {0}".format(e))
    q.remove(e)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python365\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-18-63a1d575cfeb>", line 1, in <module>
    for e in q:
RuntimeError: deque mutated during iteration
remove the 4
```

why raise the RuntimeError?

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify a `deque` while iterating over it.

A typical pattern with queues is to use a `while` loop instead, and remove items from the desired end, with `deque.pop()` or `deque.popleft()`.

E.g.:

```
>>> q = deque([4,5,6,7,8])
>>> while q:
...     element = q.pop()
...     print('removed {}'.format(element))
...
removed 8
removed 7
removed 6
removed 5
removed 4
```

or:

```
>>> q = deque([4,5,6,7,8])
>>> while q:
...     element = q.popleft()
...     print('removed {}'.format(element))
...
removed 4
removed 5
removed 6
removed 7
removed 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the deque while iterating over it. If you want to remove its elements one by one, you have to iterate over a copy of it:

```
q = deque([4,5,6,7,8])
copy = list(q)

for e in copy:
    print("remove the {0}".format(e))
    q.remove(e)
```

Or, if you want to remove all elements at once:

```
q.clear()
```